# Search query with quotes

Tags: search

I'm trying to search through WP_Query in wordpress, in custom post types. I have this request

```
$wp_query = Wp_Query(['post_type' => 'property', 's' => 'test']);
```

This works perfect. but when my property has title with apostrophe like `test's`, it doesnt work, after enter into search page in my search attribute I got `test\'s`, and when I try to find posts by this attribute that doesnt work, also when I hardcode change search string without backslash.

Any ideas how to solve this? With some custom filter or something like that? Something about more complex search with WP_Query.

Answer (score -1):

using the \' escape works for me, so whatever is causing your issue is something else with your website.  I checked with the code below:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( ['post_type' => 'post', 's' => 'Hello\'s'] );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
     $the_query->the_post();
     echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
  }
     echo '</ul>';
     }
```

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: No I didnt.....

Comment: oh, nice downvote :)